# Second degree partial differential equation with variable-change

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

**Edit:**
@Etienne mentioned that I did a typo, writing $u_y' = -xye^{-y}$ instead of $u_y' = -xe^{-y}$. I've corrected that in the calculations and now it's closer to being correct! Though I still miss $e^{-y}$ multiplicated with $f_{uv}''$ to get the correct answer.

**Problem:**
Transform the differential equation:

$$
x\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial x \,\partial y} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} =  xe^{-2y}
$$

by introducing:
$$ 
\begin{cases}
u = &xe^{-y} \\
v = &y
\end{cases}
$$

**How I am solving it.** Rewrite to:
$$
xf_{xy}'' + f_{yx}'' + f_{x} = xe^{-2y}
$$

solve $x$ and $y$ in $u$ and $v$:
$$
\begin{cases}
x = &\frac{u}{e^{-v}} \\
y = &v
\end{cases}
$$

And calculate:
$$
\begin{cases}
u_x' = & e^{-y} \\
u_y' = & -xe^{-y}
\end{cases} 
$$
$$
\begin{cases}
v_x' = & 0 \\
v_y' = & 1
\end{cases} 
$$

Find $f_x'$ by using the chainrule:
$$
f_x' = f_u' \cdot u_x' + f_v' \cdot v_x' = f_u' \cdot e^{-y}+f_v'\cdot0=f_u'e^{-y}
$$

set $g=f_u'$ and $h=f_v'$ and calculate $f_{xx}''$

$$
f_x' = f_u'e^{-y} \underbrace{= }_{g=f_u'} ge^{-y}
$$
$$
f_{xx}'' = g_x' \cdot e^{-y}
$$

Find $g_x'$ (using chainrule):
$$
g_x' = g_u' \cdot u_x' + g_v' \cdot v_x' = g_u' \cdot e^{-y} + g_v' \cdot 0 =  g_u' \cdot e^{-y} \underbrace{= }_{g=f_u'} (f_u')_u' \cdot e^{-y} = f_{uu}'' \cdot e^{-y}
$$

insert $g_x'$ in $f_{xx}''$ gives:
$$
f_{xx}'' \underbrace{=}_{g_x' = f_{uu}'' \cdot e^{-y}} (f_{uu}'' \cdot e^{-y}) \cdot e^{-y} = f_{uu}'' \cdot e^{-2y} \underbrace{=}_{y=v} f_{uu}'' \cdot e^{-2v}
$$

Now I have $f_x'$ and  $f_{xx}''$ and I only need $f_{yx}''$ to insert the differentials ito the original equation. But $f_{yx}''$ can be found using $(f_x')_y'$ since $f_{xy}'' = f_{yx}''$.

$$
f_{xy}'' = -ge^{-y} + g_y'e^{-y}
$$

Find $g_y'$ (using chainrule):
$$
g_y' = g_u' \cdot u_y' + g_v' \cdot v_y' = g_u' \cdot (-xe^{-y}) + g_v' \cdot 1 \underbrace{=}_{g=f_u'} (f_u')_u' \cdot (-xe^{-y}) + (f_u')_v' \cdot 1 =
$$
$$ - f_{uu}'' \cdot xe^{-y} + f_{uv}'' = - f_{uu}'' \cdot \frac{u}{e^{-v}}e^{-v} + f_{uv}'' = - f_{uu}'' \cdot u + f_{uv}''
$$

replace $g$ and $g_y'$ and translate to $u$ and $v$ instead of $x$ and $y$

$$
f_{xy}'' = -f_u' e^{-v} + (- f_{uu}''u + f_{uv}'')e^{-v} = -f_u' e^{-v} - f_{uu}''ue^{-v} + f_{uv}''e^{-v}
$$

Insert $f_{xx}''$, $f_{yx}''$ and $f_v'$ in the original equation:

$$
\frac{u}{e^{-v}} (f_{uu}'' e^{-2v}) + -f_u' e^{-v} - f_{uu}''ue^{-v} + f_{uv}''e^{-v} + f_u'e^{-v} = xe^{-2y}
$$
$f_u' e^{-v}$ and $uf_{uu}''e^{-v}$ cancels and I get
$$
f_{uv}'' = ue^{-v} = \frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial u \,\partial v}
$$

Obviously I've missed something. The terms with $f_{uu}''$ is gonna cancel out each other, but I can't figure out whats wrong. I've recalculated this assignment 3 times and it must be something Im not doing correctly, since I probably wouldnt do the same error three times in a row..

The answer is supposed to be:
$$
\frac{\partial ^2f}{\partial u \,\partial v} = u
$$

So I'm missing a $v$ in the first term and $e^{-v}$ multiplied with $f_{uv}''$

Comment: *Please share your thoughts so far!* :D

Comment: Just kidding . . .

Comment: @Shaun: Very witty!

Comment: $u'_y$ is not equal to $-xye^{-y}$.

Comment: Right. It's $-xe^{-y}$. Thanks, I'm gonna see what that gives me.

Comment: @Etienne Updated now, indeed that brought med closer..